# Extending from two classes (closed source library limitation)

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, architecture

My android app has been designed to use an AbstractActivity (A) which all the other activities (B) inherit for common lifecycle methods and other utilities. I have to use a third party library now (closed source), for which I need to extend only one of my activities (C) to extend an activity provided by the third party library (D). (D) is extending the default Android Activity.

I don't want to extend A from D (multi-level inheritance) because the logic from D is used in only 1 activity and may override something which D isn't ready for. I don't want C to stop extending A and move to D either..there is a lot of code duplication. D is closed source, so I cannot copy stuff around.

Is there a way to deal with such cases ? I am in early phases of development, so I can consider some major re-designs too..any suggestions will help !

Comment: It's not quite clear the intention and goal of extending D by C - the answer will depend on it. If it's just for functionality reuse, usually composition is preferred. It you need C to have D interface, an adapter of some kind would be useful. So would be good to add some details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This classic adapter pattern:  [Implementing Class Adapter Pattern in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305784/implementing-class-adapter-pattern-in-java)

Instantiate D as a member variable of C, then call it when that member is called on C.